# Getting Data from a JObject

Tags: c#, asp.net, json.net

I have stored JSON data in a string and by using the `JObject`, I am trying to get values from JSON data. I am just not able to figure out that what is the underlying issue with my code because I am not able to get data from the JSON object. A snippet of my code is attached below. If some can help me out to figure out the issue it will be immensely appreciated.

```
String text;
try {
    var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        text = sr.ReadToEnd();
        JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(text);

        string haha = (string)jObject["value/segments/requests/count/sum"];
        ViewBag.gotstring = haha;
    }

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(text);
} catch(Exception e) {
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(url);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.ToString()); }

return View();
```

Here is the JSON:

```
{
  "value": {
    "start": "2018-08-12T04:44:38.941Z",
    "end": "2018-08-12T16:44:38.941Z",
    "interval": "PT30M",
    "segments": [
      {
        "start": "2018-08-12T14:00:00Z",
        "end": "2018-08-12T14:30:00Z",
        "segments": [
          {
            "requests/count": {
              "sum": 2
            },
            "request/name": "GET Home/Index"
          },
          {
            "requests/count": {
              "sum": 1
            },
            "request/name": "GET Home/About"
          },
          {
            "requests/count": {
              "sum": 1
            },
            "request/name": "GET Home/Contact"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "start": "2018-08-12T14:30:00Z",
        "end": "2018-08-12T15:00:00Z",
        "segments": [
          {
            "requests/count": {
              "sum": 2
            },
            "request/name": "GET Account/Register"
          },
          {
            "requests/count": {
              "sum": 1
            },
            "request/name": "GET Account/Login"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "start": "2018-08-12T15:30:00Z",
        "end": "2018-08-12T16:00:00Z",
        "segments": [
          {
            "requests/count": {
              "sum": 8
            },
            "request/name": "GET Home/Index"
          },
          {
            "requests/count": {
              "sum": 8
            },
            "request/name": "GET Home/About"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: So what is the value of `text`?

Comment: @trailmax we do get this value in the string named "text". But the issue is we are not able to get the desired value out of this string using parse object.

Answer (score 2):

`jObject` does not work this way. It returns dictionary that you can query by key, but keys are single level. I.e. you'll be able to get some data like this:

```
var haha = jObject["value"]["segments"];
```

But beyond that it gets very complex. You'll be much better off defining a C# class that represents your JSON and serialise into that. A simple `Edit=>Paste Special => JSON as Class" in Visual Studio gives this:

```
    public class Rootobject
    {
        public Value value { get; set; }
    }

    public class Value
    {
        public DateTime start { get; set; }
        public DateTime end { get; set; }
        public string interval { get; set; }
        public Segment[] segments { get; set; }
    }

    public class Segment
    {
        public DateTime start { get; set; }
        public DateTime end { get; set; }
        public Segment1[] segments { get; set; }
    }

    public class Segment1
    {
       [JsonProperty("requests/count")]
       public RequestsCount requestscount { get; set; }
       [JsonProperty("request/name")]
       public string requestname { get; set; }
    }

    public class RequestsCount
    {
        public int sum { get; set; }
    }
```

and then deserialise like this:

```
var serialised = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json);

var haha = serialised.value.segments.FirstOrDefault().segments.FirstOrDefault().requestscount.sum;
```

And here is a working sample: https://dotnetfiddle.net/CZgMNE

Answer (score 1):

Can you try:

**EDIT:** seems like segments is an array, this will get you the sum for first segment only

`string haha = (string)jObject["value"]["segments"][0]["segments"]["requests/count"]["sum"];`

Comment: I get `Accessed JArray values with invalid key value: "requests/count". Int32 array index expected` exception

Comment: @trailmax just realised segments is an array and edited the answer.